# On my Macbook Pro, iTunes keeps giving me a "sign in to the iTunes Store" popup (over 50 times).

Tags: itunes, apple-store

I use iTunes just to back up my daughter's iPhone. I do not want to give it my Apple ID. When I start the program, I get a whack-a-mole series of popups. I have to click "cancel" many, many times before I can do anything with the program. The number of times seems to increase with every OS update.

How do I stop this? Clicking "cancel" once would be tolerable. Dozens of times? That's ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but it does help.

In Preferences, disable any options that require access to the internet. That includes: `General > Grid view download badges` and untick `General > Automatically retrieve CD track names from the internet`; all options in Downloads and Store; and untick `Advanced > Automatically delete watched movies and TV shows`.

After disabling all of these, the number of times the popup appears may fall from dozens and dozens to just 3.